# How to get all the themes installed on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I see with a code what themes are installed on a vscode? I'm making an extension and I need to know that

Comment: Open the "Color Theme" menu using the shortcut "Ctrl+K Ctrl+T". It will list all the color themes installed on your VS Code as well as the color theme you are currently using.

Comment: you can enumerate all the installed extensions, and then inspect if they are themes, maybe by reading there `package.json` file, you can read files from the installed extensions

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was the easiest to just map through all of the VSCode extensions and filter through them all for which ones were themes. From there you can go into `extensionPath` property and look for the theme folder which should contain the JSON of the theme.

```
// returns all the extensions that VSCode knows of
let extensions = vscode.extensions.all;

// filter through the extensions for extensions with the category of "themes"
let extensionsPaths = extensions.filter(e => {
    if (e.packageJSON.categories && e.packageJSON.categories.indexOf("Themes") != -1) {
        return true;
    }
// returns the directory of each of the extensions
}).map(e => e.extensionPath)
console.log(extensionsPaths)
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.